# how to get words of clusters

Tags: python, k-means, doc2vec

How can I get the words of each cluster

I divided them into groups

````
    LabeledSentence1 = gensim.models.doc2vec.TaggedDocument
    all_content_train = []
    j=0
    for em in train['KARMA'].values:
        all_content_train.append(LabeledSentence1(em,[j]))
        j+=1
    print('Number of texts processed: ', j)


    d2v_model = Doc2Vec(all_content_train, vector_size = 100, window = 10, min_count = 500, workers=7, dm = 1,alpha=0.025, min_alpha=0.001)
    d2v_model.train(all_content_train, total_examples=d2v_model.corpus_count, epochs=10, start_alpha=0.002, end_alpha=-0.016)```



    ```kmeans_model = KMeans(n_clusters=10, init='k-means++', max_iter=100)
    X = kmeans_model.fit(d2v_model.docvecs.doctag_syn0)
    labels=kmeans_model.labels_.tolist()
    l = kmeans_model.fit_predict(d2v_model.docvecs.doctag_syn0)
    pca = PCA(n_components=2).fit(d2v_model.docvecs.doctag_syn0)
    datapoint = pca.transform(d2v_model.docvecs.doctag_syn0)
````

I can get the text and its cluster but how can I learn the words which mainly created those groups

Answer (score 0):

It's not an inherent feature of `Doc2Vec` to list words most-related to any document or doc-vector. (Other algorithms, such as LDA, will offer that.)

So, you could potentially write your own code, once you've split your documents into clusters, to report the words that are "most over-represented" in each cluster.

For example, calculate every word's frequency in the entire corpus, then each word's frequency in each cluster. For each cluster, report the N words whose in-cluster-frequency is the largest multiple of the full-corpus-frequency. Would this give helpful results on your data, for your needs? You'd have to try it.

Separately, regarding your use of `Doc2Vec`:

- there's no good reason to alias the existing class `TaggedDocument` to a strange class name like `LabeldSentence1`. Just use `TaggedDocument` directly.
- if you supply your corpus, `all_content_train`, to the object-inittialization – as your code does – then you **don't** need to also call `train()`. Training will have already happened automatically. If you do want more than the default amount of training (`epochs=5`), just supply a larger `epochs` value to the initialization.
- the learning-rate values you've supplied to `train()` – `start_alpha=0.002, end_alpha=-0.016` – are nonsensical & destructive. Few users should need to tinker with these `alpha` values at all, but especially, they should never **increase** from the beginning to end of a training cycle, as these values do.
- If you were running with logging enabled at the INFO level, and/or watching the output closely, you would likely see readouts and warnings indicating that excessive training was happening, or problematic values used.